# Dynamically change the content of of control based on a value

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to achieve the following behavior:
Depending on a value use a different datatemplate:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="cardTemplate2">
                    <Border x:Name="container">
                     .....
                    </Border>

                  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowSecondDT}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Child" TargetName="container">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
```

The application fails claiming that Setter Property="Child" is null...

Another information is that this Datatemplate in the resource of a control: (devexpress gris)

```
<dxg:GridControl      xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
x:Name="gridTitulaire"        DataSource="{Binding Contacts}" Width="600" >
                <dxg:GridControl.Resources>

                    <DataTemplate x:Key="cardTemplate2">
                    <Border x:Name="container">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >

                            </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isTitulairePrincipal}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Child" TargetName="container">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>

                </dxg:GridControl.Resources>
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

                  <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="first_name"/>
                  <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="last_name"/>

                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                  <dxg:CardView  x:Name="view" ShowGroupedColumns="True" CardTemplate="{DynamicResource cardTemplate2}"  />
                </dxg:GridControl.View>
              </dxg:GridControl>
```

Any idea ?
Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two separate data templates (call them `CardTemplateV` for the vertical one, and `CardTemplateH` for the horizontal one, for example), and set the CardTemplateSelector to a selector object that checks the discriminating field.

Example:

```
class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var cardData = item as CardData;
        if (cardData == null) return null;
        var dataObject = cardData.DataContext as YourDataType;
        if (dataObject == null) return null;
        if (dataObject.isTitulairePrincipal)
            return (DataTemplate)App.Current.FindResource("CardTemplateV");
        else 
            return (DataTemplate)App.Current.FindResource("CardTemplateH");
    }
}
```

In the XAML add the selector to the resource dictionary and reference it from the grid:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:YourTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<dxg:CardView
    x:Name="view" 
    ShowGroupedColumns="True" 
    CardTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>
...
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like it is the right way. However the var dataObject = item as YourDataType; line returns a DevExpress.Wpf.Grid.CardData type... not my object...

Comment: Ok i'll modify my example then, or you can go ahead and do it yourself, just extract your dataobject from its DataContext property.

Comment: Ok, after some other stuffs (i had to retrieve the value from the grid manually) it works !
How did you know that devexpress grid had a CarTemplateSelector ?
Anyway, you did it. Thanks !!!!!!

Comment: It's general practice in WPF that wherever you have an `ItemTemplate` you also have an `ItemTemplateSelector` so I extrapolated and googled `CardTemplateSelector` and found that it existed... By the way, the `DataContext` approach as I wrote in my example above, doesn't work?